# Identify low-color jpeg images

Tags: colors, jpeg

From a large collection of jpeg images, I want to identify those more likely to be simple logos or text (as opposed to camera pictures).  One identifying characteristic would be low color count.  I expect most to have been created with a drawing program.

If a jpeg image has a palette, it's simple to get a color count.  But I expect most files to be 24-bit color images.  There's no restriction on image size.

I suppose I could create an array of 2^24 (16M) integers, iterate through every pixel and inc the count for that 24-bit color.  Yuck.  Then I would count the non-zero entries.  But if the jpeg compression messes with the original colors I could end up counting a lot of unique pixels, which might be hard to distinguish from a photo.  (Maybe I could convert each pixel to YUV colorspace, and save fewer counts.)

Any better ideas?  Library suggestions?  Humorous condescensions?

Answer (score 0):

Sample 10000 random coordinates and make a histogram, then analyze the histogram.

Comment: I like the idea of taking a random sample.  But "analyze the histogram" sounds like one of those things easier said than done.  It's easy to spot these logos by eye, but algorithmically may be a lot harder.